# Which Falcon-9 launches were of a Falcon-9R rocket?

Tags: spacex, terminology, falcon-9

I have heard about Falcon 9 1.1 and Falcon 9 FT, but what is a Falcon 9R?

If I understand correctly R = "reusable" which seems to apply to a lot of them.

Are the Falcon 9 FT rockets launched today also Falcon 9 R's?

To get to the bottom of the tagging issues [falcon-9](/questions/tagged/falcon-9) vs [falcon9-r](/questions/tagged/falcon9-r) I've just asked in meta [How to determine on which questions the falcon9-r and falcon-9 tags do and don't belong?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2840/12102)

I'm also uncertain about the results of the older question [Can we merge [falcon9-r] into [falcon-9]?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1295/12102)

But here, I'd like to ask: Which Falcon-9 launches were of a Falcon-9R rocket? Do the "FT" and "R" qualifiers overlap? Does anybody still use "Falcon 9 R"?

Answer (score 8):

According to Wikipedia "F9R Dev" was [an intermediate development type for early landing and reuse tests of the Falcon 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_9_prototypes#F9R_Dev1_flight_tests). A single vehicle flew four times successfully before being lost.

I haven't seen "Falcon 9R" or "F9R" in use other than that. The tag description describes a cryptid with reusable first *and second* stages.

Comment: "In its F9R configuration, the launcher has all characteristics of the Falcon 9 v1.1 with the addition of four landing legs, a cold gas attitude control system and four grid fins to the first stage." - https://spaceflight101.com/spacerockets/falcon-9-v1-1-f9r/